# Quickbook online service gives 500 internal server?

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to call the data service but got 500 error every time. When I tested using "Try it" button in the API Explorer, it worked. The response came back fine. But in my app, it failed to connect. The same OAuth header worked for the API but not inside the app.

```
String urlReq = "https://qbo.sbfinance.intuit.com/resource/companymetadata/v2/" + intuitRealmID; //static baseURL
Uri uriToIntuit = new Uri(urlReq);
HttpWebRequest intuitReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriToIntuit);
intuitReq.Method = "GET";
intuitReq.ContentType = "text/xml";
intuitReq.ContentLength = 0;
intuitReq.Accept = "text/xml";
OAuthUtils.signRequest(intuitReq, ap.ConsumerKey, ap.ConsumerSecret, rToken.Token,rToken.TokenSecret);

HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(intuitReq.GetResponse());
```

...

```
public static void signRequest(HttpWebRequest request, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string token, string tokenSecret)
{
    string normalizedUrl;
    string normalizedRequestParameters;

    string timeStamp = OAuthUtils.GenerateTimeStamp();
    string nonce = OAuthUtils.GenerateNonce();

    OAuthConsumerBase consumerBase = new OAuthConsumerBase();
    string signature = consumerBase.GenerateSignature(
        request.RequestUri,
        null,           // callback,
        null,           // verifier,
        consumerKey,
        consumerSecret,
        token,          // token,
        null,           // type,
        tokenSecret,    // tokenSecret,
        request.Method,
        timeStamp,
        nonce,
        null,           // status,
        out normalizedUrl,
        out normalizedRequestParameters
    );

    string authHeader = OAuthRequest.GenerateAuthHeader(
            nonce,
            timeStamp,
            signature,
            token,
            consumerKey,
            null,           // verifier
            null,           // callback
            "HMAC-SHA1",    // signature type
            "1.0"           // version
        );

    request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = authHeader;
}
```

I have tried the static baseURL which also gives 500 error.
https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/rest/user/v2/

```
OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_nonce=\"c830ffa8338b4d6fa0b3e8d03f144642\", oauth_timestamp=\"1374015013\", oauth_consumer_key=\"qyprdpwcmwYdE7nfBkG4Mb0t65ufH8\", oauth_token=\"qyprdTnNWcIBorQk9L93o8ERKPZI3ELoBUHBrULzvsxPsPMU\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_signature=\"Ws0WpQmV9aAzaFHw%2B6wMC5aidBk%3D\""       string
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the endpoint directly, you can try the C# devkit. ( I'll try to share some codes related to this approach also ).

IDS Devkit Download - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/0100_installing_the_ipp_.net_devkit

```
using Intuit.Ipp.Core;
using Intuit.Ipp.Security;
using Intuit.Ipp.Services;
using Intuit.Ipp.Data;
using Intuit.Ipp.AsyncServices;
using Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo; 

OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(
"a",
"b",
"c",
"d"
);
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext (oauthValidator, companyID, IntuitServicesType.QBO);
DataServices objDataService = new DataServices(context);
```

Using this dataServices object, try to call any endpoint and check if it is working fine. 
If it works plz capture the raw http request using some tools like fiddler. You can compare that with the same of the previous approach.

Sync Call - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/0299_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

Asyn Call - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/0300_asynchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

Although apps on boarded with 7.0 or later should use the static base URL but you can just check what dynamic URL you are getting corresponding to your company's relam.
Ref https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/0100_calling_data_services/0010_getting_the_base_url#Getting_the_Base_URL_at_Runtime

Please let me know how it goes.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but DevKit is not an option here. Our app has been working fine with QB Desktop. Is there something special about QB Online? Set up something else? The error message is too generic.

Comment: The accept content type was wrong. I was using "text/xml" for QB desktop. But it didn't work for QB Online. 
    intuitReq.Accept = "application/xml";

Answer (score 0):

You can download the sample app for dotnet from:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_code

Just enter your key values in the web.config and you should be set.